# SQLite select with ACCENTS

Tags: python, sqlite

I am currently coding a small program in python, with PyQt. Without going into details, I create a 'price' table with sqlite3 in a module, and I use PyQt to do searches and display them.

But I run into a few small issues when I want to do research. My price table contains,, a name field. These names sometimes have accented characters, and the search I do with LIKE is accent-sensitive, which I don't want.

When I type "echec" I would like "échec", "échèc", etc. to be potentially returned.

Answer (score 2):

You've got to apply a **[collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms144250(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)** to your select like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Price 
WHERE Name Like '%echec%' COLLATE NOACCENTS
```

After **[defining your NOACCENT collation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html)**.

Comment: thanks for your respond, i dont know how to define a noaccent collation

Comment: Check the link in my answer, or [this one](https://wellsr.com/python/making-new-collations-with-python-sqlite-create_collation/)